# How to cut a movie into quarters & display on 4 monitors?

Tags: delphi, video

I would like to make a big display by putting monitors side by side.

Any layout (3x4, etc), but let's stick with 2x2 for now.

Presumably I have to open the video file, get each frame, divide it into 4 and write each part into a new video file (with suitable header).

Are there any FOSS components or libraries which can help with this, or do I have to code it all myself?

Oh, btw, I would also like to do the same with still images.

---

Update: I might need *many* and had been thinking of a windows based controller communicating over TCP/IP with a bunch of embedded devices, one per display.  I thought that wasn't relevant to the question, but it might prevent people looking for alternative solutions.

---

Update: thanks for all of the comments & questions. I might need to drive up to 20x20 monitors or maybe even more (think of a "video wall" made from 21" TFT).

If one single magic graphic card can handle this, then that is obviously the way to go.

Otherwise, I will have a "controller" PC which allows the user to select video files and then slices them appropriately and sends each section to one MCU which controls a single display. The MCUs will store their slice of each video stream and later the controller will send a short command over TCP/IP to tell each to start playing it's slice of video # X. That ought to keep them in synch (I thought that I would *have to* do that, which is why the original question didn't even bother to explain, just to ask how to slice).

Comment: Why can't you just make the window displaying the video be stretched across the four monitors? Then you don't have to do any splitting.

Comment: +1 would you care to elaborate upon that?

Comment: If you are in control of the video window, set the top left coordinate of the video window to the top left of the top-left most monitor, and set the bottom right coordinate to the bottom right of the bottom-right most monitor... So you video will be stretched over all the monitors and you are letting the video driver do the splitting for you.

Comment: If you split the video into multiple videos, how are you going to keep them in sync when you play them?

Comment: +1 to each. Yes, synching worries me (but would it be discriminable?).  I just don't know enough about video control to understand how to implement @Nat's answer :-(

Comment: Wait, wouldn't @Nat's answer mean that my PC has a graphic card (or cards) with enough physical connections for all of the monitors? I might need *many* and had been thinking of a windows based controller communicating over TCP/IP with a bunch of embedded devices, one per display.

Comment: My idea only works if you have one computer with many screens/graphic cards. If you want to do more, then it gets harder. There a lots of products out there that do this. They are called "Media Servers" and are used not only for a bunch of screens, they are also used for LED screens, projecters and lights. The simple ones essentially do what my initial suggestions was. See http://www.arkaos.net/product/index.php?catid=2&pid=10031&iid=74 for an example.

Comment: Insufficient Input. 

Is this a single video, as in one particular video, or any video such as one a user would pick? 

What is the input type - Is it a disk based file or streaming?

Is this an end user app, or just something for a specific use?

What are your speed requirements? Is it something that needs to happen on the fly, or can you have a processing time, then play the video?

Comment: +1 to both & I will try to clarify the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `mencoder` with the `-vf` option and use `crop=b:h:x:y` as a filter.

By doing this (bxh=n) times you can generate the necessary number of videos even from a batchfile.

For still images the analogous solution is `convert` with the `-crop` option

Answer (score 1):

Using DirectShow you can render a portion of a video image to different monitors using an Infinite Pin Tee and multiple renderers as shown below.

[image]

The amount of monitors a single PC can support depends on CPU and Graphics grunt.

Syncing across multiple computers is not as simple as sending a play message via TCP - this would just not work. I would recommend setting up one computer as a sync master which plays video normally and each sync slave would be listen and seek to timecode send out from the master.

Video encoding can also have a impact on the ability to sync effectively so don't encode with any intra frames, a MJPEG codec could be a good choice.

Image overlays will have to be done on a per renderer basis and the method used depends on the choice of renderer. The example above uses the EVR and so overlays could be done with IMFVideoMixerBitmap.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ffmpeg oe mencoder(based on ffmpeg), if you want to write codes to finish that job, you can done it by using opencv.